# Python Sklearn ValueError: Y contains previously unseen labels

Tags: nlp, text-classification

How can i fix this error:

```
Input In [148], in <cell line: 2>()
      3     output = model(new_resume_input_ids, new_jd_input_ids, new_adj_matrix)
      4     print(output)
----> 5     predicted_label = label_encoder.inverse_transform(torch.argmax(output, dim=1).cpu().numpy().flatten())[0]
      8 print(f'Predicted Label: {predicted_label}')

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_label.py:161, in LabelEncoder.inverse_transform(self, y)
    159 diff = np.setdiff1d(y, np.arange(len(self.classes_)))
    160 if len(diff):
--> 161     raise ValueError("y contains previously unseen labels: %s" % str(diff))
    162 y = np.asarray(y)
    163 return self.classes_[y]

ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels: [ 35  85 132 262 307]
```

I am trying to predict the label of resume using GAT Classifier